# DevServer contentBase deprecation warning and Invalid character in header content

Tags: typescript, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

Here's my Webpack 4 and DevServer 3 configuration.

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.js']
    },
    mode: 'development',
    target: 'node',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx$/,
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'source-map-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                enforce: 'pre'
            },
            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                loader: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'style.css' })
    ]
};
```

The console output only shows this warning:

```
‼ ｢wds｣: Using a URL as contentBase is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version. Please use the proxy option instead.
```

As I try to visit the page specified in the Webpack console output at http://localhost:12073/ I receive another error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in header content ["Location"]
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:473:3)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:232:21)
    at app.get (d:\Работы\Maxilect\RepoLister\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:353:13)
...
```

The `public` folder also contains `index.html` with the content of

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
        <title>Repo Lister</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/dist/style.css' />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='app'></div>
        <script src='/dist/bundle.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please assist. The Webpack configuration seems OK to me.

**UP.** Changing the devServer configuration to

```
devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '*': path.join(__dirname, 'public')
        },
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
```

resulted in this error: `[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request / from localhost:39515 to d:\Jobs\lalala\RepoLister\public (ECONNREFUSED)`

Answer (score 0):

The same code runs Ok on Ubuntu 16. It seems the issue was the latest versions of Webpack and devServer running on Windows 8.